# Why is my Powershell script suddenly failing with an error? It's been working for months with no changes

Tags: powershell

The script included below is now suddenly failing because of the following error.  I have not made any changes to it and it's been working for months.

```
Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\ImportScripts\FedEx Script\FedExScript.ps1:14 char:14
+     Rename-Item $file $newfilename
+                 ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
    $curdir=Get-Location
    $unc=" " #redacted, but confirmed that working location is correct when running
    Set-Location $unc
    $dayofweek=([int](Get-date).DayOfWeek)
    $fileday=-($dayofweek+3) #change if needed 4:Wednesday, 3:Thursday, etc
    $ndate=get-date ((get-date).adddays($fileday)) -Format "yyyyMMdd"
    $nyear=get-date ((get-date).adddays($fileday)) -Format "yyyy"
    $filename="FedEx_ShipmentDetail_"+$ndate+"*.csv"
    $newfilename="FedEx_ShipmentDetail_"+$ndate+".csv"
    $fileexists=Test-Path "FedEx_ShipmentDetail_*.csv" -PathType Leaf
    if ($fileexists) {
        $file = gci ($filename)
        Rename-Item $file $newfilename
        Set-Location $curdir
        $err=cscript "C:\ImportScripts\FedEx Script\FedExScript.vbs"
        if ($err -eq 0) {
            cscript "C:\ImportScripts\upscleanuptemp.vbs"
            Set-Location $unc
            mv $newfilename .\$nyear
            Set-Location $curdir
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Import and cleanup completed with no errors.")
        }
        else {
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Error in FedExScript.vbs  "+$err)
            Set-Location $unc
            Rename-Item $newfilename $file
            Set-Location $curdir
        }
    }
    else {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("File not found.")
        Set-Location $curdir
    }
```

Comment: The implication is that `gci ($filename)` produces no output, which in turn implies that there is no file matching pattern `"FedEx_ShipmentDetail_"+$ndate+"*.csv"` in the current directory.

Comment: Thank you, IDK why I missed this.  The filename was indeed incorrect and I needed to adjust the $fileday modifying integer for the script to work.  Not paying attention to my own comments SMH..

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Needed to adjust $fileday modifying integer because filename was not matching, as noted in my comments.